# Alma Linux - Not able to ping out

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, virtual-machines

So I have my first VM in Proxmox and I know the network works as I have used CT in the past without any issues, however I have set up a VM and now I am having network issues.

Seems while it says the network is connected, I can't ping out to 8.8.8.8

I am wondering how do I know if the network connection is valid in Alma Linux.

basically these are the settings I need.

```
Address:   124.150.139.3/29
Netmask:   255.255.255.248
Network:   124.150.139.0
Broadcast: 124.150.139.7
HostMin:   124.150.139.1
HostMax:   124.150.139.6
```

I know the gateway is `124.150.139.1`
I know the IP address I want to assign is `124.150.139.3`
I know the DNS is `8.8.8.8`

This is what it shows when I do `ip a`
[image: IP a]

This is my ifcfg file.

[image: ifcfg file.]

Comment: Can you post the output of `traceroute -n 8.8.8.8`?